# In SQL Server 2008, do relationships make queries faster?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

For example, if I have a `BlogPosts` table, and a `PostCategory` table, where the `BlogPosts` table has a FK field `PostCategoryId`. Would a relationship make the query faster, or is it more of a data quality thing?

What about when a join table is involved? Take the `PostCategoryId` field out of the `BlogPosts` table, and have a table "between" them called `PostsInCategories`, which has only 2 FK fields: `BlogPostId` and `PostCategoryId`, combined for form a PK.

Do relationships improve queries there?

Comment: Creating and using additional tables with foreign keys slows down both selects and modifications. But this approach improves the design

Comment: My understanding is that it will actually make it slower, but will help you maintain referential integrity.  If you were going for absolute optimization, relationships will generally slow you down.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647193/database-relationships

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Foreign key relationships are about **enforcing data integrity**, e.g. making sure you don't have any "voodoo" child rows that don't have a parent row anymore, and so forth.

Foreign key relationships on their own do not boost your performance since SQL Server will **not** create any indices automatically for foreign keys.

For several reasons (boost performance when enforcing referential integrity and increase JOIN performance - see [Kimberly Tripp's blog post on the topic](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/When-did-SQL-Server-stop-putting-indexes-on-Foreign-Key-columns.aspx)) it is very much a recommended step to add indices to all foreign key fields in your tables - and adding those indices will speed up queries that will use those FK relationships.

Comment: Thanks marc_s. I thought was the case, just wanted to be sure.

Comment: "add indices to all foreign key fields " -- such blanket advice is inappropriate. The usual criteria will apply e.g. if the selectivity would be high (i.e. many duplicated values in the FK) them it may be better to omit the index in a high activity environment (i.e. many updates).

Comment: Sure, I read the section of FKs but it doesn't address the counter view i.e. when omitting am index might be a good idea i.e. lacks balance.

Comment: "I have not yet ever heard any reasoning why an index on a FK column would be a bad idea" -- I can help :) Coincidentally, I was looking at [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275561) earlier today. Background: Access (a.k.a. Jet) used to always add indexes to both sides of a FK but then they realised that this isn't always a good idea, so introduced the 'fast foreign keys' feature:

Comment: Quote: "In cases where the values in a foreign key index are highly duplicated, using an index can be less efficient than simply scanning the table. maintaining such an index as records are inserted and deleted from the table, can degrade performance even further." Seems to me the same can be said of SQL Server, no?

Comment: They both use b-trees but let's not debate that. Rather, I'll leave you with two thoughts: can you imagine an environment where updates far exceed queries and the cost of maintaining a highly selective index is not beneficial? And how about all those articles I've read about not creating an index if it would be highly selective: why do they not mention FKs as an exception to the rule?

Comment: @onedaywhen I think this string of comments would have been better in a separate answer, or perhaps a blog post :)

Comment: @ElRonnoco: did you realize that this was a back and forth between marc_c and myself but the former subsequently deleted their comments? I left mine because they are still valid i.e. that blanket advice such as "add indices to all foreign key fields" is merely a rule of thumb and that there are exceptional circumstances e.g. high selectivity index in a high activity environment.

Comment: My apologies, I did not realise that. Your point is valid though and I think would benefit from being consolidated into a single answer to the original post. Thanks :)